# How to customise Bulma variables via Nuxt/Buefy?

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

How can I customise Bulma variables when using Nuxt and Buefy?

It seems Nuxt is loading Bulma/Buefy before it loads my Sass vars, where I set my custom values.

**nuxt.config.js**:

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  head: {},
  css: [
    '~/assets/bulma-vars.sass'
  ],
  plugins: [],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  ],
  modules: [
    ['nuxt-buefy', {css: true}],
  ],
  build: {}
}
```

**bulma-vars.sass**:

```
$danger: orange
```

How can I set my vars before Bulma/Buefy is initiated?

[--- UPDATE ---]

Following @kissu's idea of doing this via a plugin, I set to work on this.

**nuxt.config.js**:

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/set-bulma-vars.js'
],
```

**plugins/set-bulma-vars.js**

```
@import '~/assets/set-bulma-vars.sass'
```

**assets/set-bulma-vars.sass**

```
$danger: #00f
```

...but it doesn't seem to the variables in a scope such that Bulma can inherit them, and subsequently my vars are ignored (though the plugin CSS *is* loaded.)

So the only way I've solved this so far is via my own answer, below.

Comment: Maybe check this one: https://github.com/buefy/nuxt-buefy/issues/28#issue-365328381

Comment: This one looks interesting too, even if probably not needed: https://github.com/buefy/nuxt-buefy/issues/9#issuecomment-616625670

Comment: Oh - I've just found some official guidelines on this on the [Buefy GitHub](https://github.com/buefy/nuxt-buefy#customization) page. Annoyingly, these steps seem to be absent from the Buefy docs, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a `/assets/scss/custom_buefy.scss` file with variables like this

```css
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";
// the line above is important

$primary: hsl(168, 59%, 47%);
$link: hsl(24, 94%, 66%);
$info: hsl(200, 100%, 75%);
...
```

To customize our application.

Then created a `/plugins/vue-buefy.js` file to import it

```js
import '~/assets/scss/custom_buefy.scss'
```

And then, imported it into our `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
plugins: [
  { src: '@/plugins/vue-buefy', mode: 'client' },
],
```

Working good so far. Maybe not the best configuration, but flexible enough for customizing the CSS and also importing some specific components on demand (and not the whole library).

---

My starting point was not the CLI tho (I do use the `buefy` package), so YMMV.

Comment: Spasibo also for introducing me to the initialism "YMMV". Kruto :-)

Comment: Sorry, I realised later that you did include the plugin content - I just didn't recognise it as I didn't realise you could import CSS in a JS plugin. Anyway, I tried this approach (see question edit) and, although the CSS was successfully imported, the Bulma var overrides didn't take effect, so I guess it's a scoping issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is what I did.

First, disable auto-loading of Buefy in `nuxt.config.js` > `modules`:

```
modules: [
    ['nuxt-buefy', {css: false}],
]
```

This solves the problem of Buefy (and Bulma) loading before we have chance to set any theme variables.

Next, create a Sass file e.g. `bulma-vars.css`:

```
$danger: orange
@import "~bulma/bulma"
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy"
```

(`~bulma/bulma` and `~buefy/src/scss/buefy` are the relative paths to the main Bulma Sass file and Buefy SCSS file, respectively, within `node_modules`.)

Add this to `nuxt.config.js` > `css`:

```
css: [
    '~/assets/bulma-vars.sass'
]
```

There's probably better ways (I've seen references to doing this via the [Nuxt style-resources module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources), or via a custom plugin - see [@kissu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414279/1352288)) but this at least works.